# Specify Variable Initialization Order in Scala

Tags: scala

I have a special class `Model` that needs to have its methods called in a very specific order.

I tried doing something like this:

```
val model = new Model

new MyWrappingClass {
 val first = model.firstMethod()
 val second = model.secondMethod()
 val third = model.thirdMethod()

}
```

The methods should be called in the order listed, however I am seeing an apparently random order.

**Is there any way to get the variable initialization methods to be called in a particular order?**

Comment: How do you tell it's called in random order?

Comment: @thirstycrow It seems that way due to an error I am having.  But even if it turns out to be something else I am interested in knowing.  This should be a Scala spec but I could not find it.

Comment: You sure, this is as close to your actual code as you think? When I implement it with `println` in the model methods, the order seems to be correct. Your actual code does not declare these vals as `lazy val` by any chance?

Comment: @SaschaKolberg No lazy vals, this is as close as it gets.  It could well be that most of the time they execute in order, but how about *all* of the time?

Comment: I think, there is something crucial missing. Unless your methods are not doing something concurrently or you have a more complex inheritance hierarchy this looks pretty straight forward sequential to me.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt your methods are called in the wrong order. But to be sure, you can try something like this:

```
val (first, second, third) = (
   model.firstMethod(),
   model.secondMethod(),
   model.thirdMethod()
)
```

You likely have some other problem with your code.

Answer (score 0):

I can run 100 million loops where it never gets the order wrong, as follows:

```
class Model {
   var done = Array(false,false,false);
   def firstMethod():Boolean =  { done(0) = true; done(1) || done(2) };
   def secondMethod():Boolean = { done(1) = true; !done(0) || done(2) };
   def thirdMethod():Boolean  = { done(2) = true; !done(0) || !done(1) };
};
```

Notice that these methods return a True if done out of order and false when called in order.

Here's your class:

```
class MyWrappingClass {
 val model = new Model;
 val first = model.firstMethod()
 val second = model.secondMethod()
 val third = model.thirdMethod()
};
```

Our function to check for bad behavior on each trial:

```
def isNaughty(w: MyWrappingClass):Boolean = { w.first || w.second || w.third };
```

A short program to test:

```
var i = 0
var b = false;

while( (i<100000000) && !b ){
       b = isNaughty(new MyWrappingClass);
       i += 1;
}

if (b){
    println("out-of-order behavior occurred");
    println(i);
} else {
    println("looks good");
}
```

Scala 2.11.7 on OpenJDK8 / Ubuntu 15.04

Of course this doesn't prove it impossible to have wrong order, only that correct behavior seems highly repeatable in a fairly simple case.